# How to connect to WPA2 encrypted wireless-network when booted from CloneZilla Live-CD?

Tags: clonezilla, backup, wpa2

My intent is to perform a backup of my laptop's (Dell Vostro 3350) sda1 disk to my desktop. After some googling I decided to use CloneZilla for that purpose. I have an OpenSSH server installed and running on my desktop. So I inserted CloneZilla CD to CD-rom, booted from it, then chose an option something like "use ssh server to store image". Then I got an invitation to choose a network interface. I chose wlan0 and entered shell to manualy configure connection. And that's where I got into trouble, for wifi-network which I wanted to use is WPA2-encrypted, and I don't know how to connect to it from command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `wpa_supplicant` to configure the WPA2 portion.  I don't recall the exact order, of whether you should run that first or iwconfig first, though.  Here's the Ubuntu man page:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/wpa_supplicant.8.html

There should be pointers elsewhere on using it correctly with whatever distro CloneZilla is based on.

Comment: Thanks so much for that hint which turned out to be very useful to me.

Answer (score 10):

Actual steps to follow:

1.create config-file for wpa_supplicant

`# touch /etc/wpa_suppl.conf`

2.edit it with vi-editor

`# vi /etc/wpa_suppl.conf`

there should be:

```
network={
    ssid="your_ssid"
    psk="your_key"
}
```

then:

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_suppl.conf -Dwext
# dhclient wlan0
```

Thats all